# Does "a[0]" mean something more than just "a"?

Tags: c, arrays

Me and a friend of mine are arguing about that so we thought
here we can get an appropriate answer, with the corresponding explanation.
`int a[0];`
is `a[0]` an array and does it have any advantages? 
(I didn't only want to know what happened if I defined a and a[0] but also want to know the advantages and how it was more than just the variable.)

Comment: I would say that in your case a is just valid as a pointer, since you cannot use any index on it

Comment: This is an interesting enough question, but it really doesn't show much effort, and the title's misleading.  An answer to the title question would, "of course, a[0] is the first element of the array, whereas a is the array.  They have different types" etc.  There are some close votes (as duplicates) that point out that a zero-size array is not permitted.

Comment: Advantages over what? And what is the context of your variable `a`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**YES, they are different according to their functionality.** 
Lets first get into their memory address.

```
int a[0];
printf("%p / %p", &a[0], &a);
```

As you can test `a[0]` uses the same address as `a`.
That means they are the same, but that doesn't mean their behaviour is the same.
That because `&a` aways points to `a[0]` which is the only one memory area allocated here.

**However.. despite the logics, `a[0]` IS considered array.**
Many people say that an array needs to have more then 1 memory block used, but thats wrong.
And that is because of the index operator `[]` which is what actually makes something an array. (systematic arrangement of objects)
Even if the object is one as it appears in here `a[0]` it is accepted as an array by the compiller and the debug. And you will have to
initialize the array in case you want to assign value INTO it.

Valid:

```
int a[] = {1};
```

Valid:

```
int a[0] = {1};
```

Invalid:

```
int a[0] = 1;
```

On top of that, converting a pointer to the array is valid as follows:

```
int a[0];
int* p;

p = a;
```

However you can't just set p to point into a one block of memory, it is reserved for the datatype. At the end we have an integer that points to itself.
The conclusion is that the compiler/debug and you by yourself can threat it like an array, but you can't use it.
(Or at least to expect propper result)
All that means that the difference between `a` an `a[0]` is the ability of `a` to point to its address.

Comment: Forgot to mention about the case where it is used as a struct member.

Comment: `int a[0];` is illegal in Standard C. If you are talking about a particular compiler's extension, please include which compiler and version you are talking about

Comment: Game-Editor's compiler for e.g, probablly the same compiler he is using, judging by his ex profile description.

Comment: I don't care about how a[0] means more than a in game editor.
Well, this answer is really detailed and tells most of the uses of how a[0] is more than just a! So 'a[0]' is an array whilst 'a' is a pointer... Thank you for the answer, really helpful.

Comment: I look'd at your profile description, you said you are developing under legendary compillers.

Answer (score 4):

As a standalone stack variable, it is not useful.  However, as the last member of a struct, it can be used as a variable length array and doing this used to be a common technique.  For example:

```
struct foo {
  int a[0];
};

struct foo* bar = malloc( sizeof *bar + 10 * sizeof *bar->a );
/* now you can (possibly) use bar->a as an array of 10 ints */
```

Note that this is a non-standard, non-portable hack and is certainly not good practice in new code.

Comment: Some corrections, if I may: variable length array is something different. It is usually called flexible array member, as defined in C99 standard. Also, `[0]` is GNU C extension, C99 defines it as `[]`. And `sizeof(bar->a)` is 0 in that particular case, it should rather be `sizeof(bar->a[0])`.

Comment: @keltar: thanks for the comments.  I edited to write `*bar->a`, as originally intended.  Possibly `bar->a[0]` is more readable.

Comment: Aha! So it does have a use as a variable length array! Thanks for the answer! Might stop arguing soon hopefully.

Comment: @TheMatrix this (without the `0`) is *flexible array member*. VLA means something else (block-scope array with size specified by a variable)